# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (0,)

Tags: vpython

My aim is to make the image1 move along the ring from its current position upto 180 degree. I have been trying to do different things but nothing seem to work. My final aim is to move both the images along the ring in different directions and finally merge them to and make them disappear.I keep getting the error above.Can you please help? Also can you tell how I can go about this problem?

```
from visual import *
import numpy as np
x = 3
y = 0
z = 0
i = pi/3
c = 0.120239 # A.U/minute
r = 1
for theta in arange(0, 2*pi, 0.1):        #range of theta values; 0 to    
  xunit = r * sin(theta)*cos(i) +x
  yunit = r * sin(theta)*sin(i) +y
  zunit = r*cos(theta) +z

ring = curve( color = color.white )       #creates a curve
for theta in arange(0, 2*pi, 0.01):

  ring.append( pos=(sin(theta)*cos(i) +x,sin(theta)*sin(i) +y,cos(theta)   +z) ) 

  image1=sphere(pos=(2.5,-0.866,0),radius=0.02, color=color.yellow)    
  image2=sphere(pos=(2.5,-0.866,0),radius=0.02, color=color.yellow) 
  earth=sphere(pos=(-3,0,-0.4),color=color.yellow, radius =0.3,material=materials.earth) #creates the observer
  d_c_p = pow((x-xunit)**2 + (y-yunit)**2 + (z-zunit)**2,0.5) #calculates the distance between the center and points on ring
  d_n_p = abs(yunit + 0.4998112152755791) #calculates the distance to the nearest point
  t1 = ( d_c_p+d_n_p)/c
  t0=d_c_p/c
  t=t1-t0                                  #calculates the time it takes from one point to another

  theta = []
  t = []
  dtheta = np.diff(theta)                  #calculates the difference in theta

  dt = np.diff(t)                          #calculates the difference in t
 speed = r*dtheta/dt                      #hence this calculates the speed

 deltat = 0.005                          
 t2=0                                      
 while True:
     rate(5)

     image2.pos = image2.pos + speed*deltat  #increments the position of the image1 
  t2 = t2 + deltat
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that image2.pos is a vector  (that's the "3" in the error message) but speed*deltat is a scalar (that's the "0" in the error message). You can't add a vector and a scalar. Instead of a scalar "speed" you need a vector velocity. There seem to be some errors in indentation in the program you posted, so there is some possibility I've misinterpreted what you're trying to do.

For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users